# Is it necessary to create a ui component(s) for a single call in one page?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I am about to create a Vue.js project and i use the smart/dumb pattern for my ui components. In my `dumb components` I have already the input, buttons and etc..., but in my `smart components` I am curios if it is really necessary to create a component if i will use that only in one page. For example. `login-form` component, then i will use that only in login page. So, ⤵️

My first question, is it really necessary to create a component for that ?

Second question, and when will i gonna create a `smart components`?

Comment: The answer is, it depends. Considering that you may end up with 1000+ lines component by not doing that, it makes sense at some point or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Moving code to another components makes code of initial component more readable. Even if you are going to use that new components only once.
2. Usually *smart components* - are pages that fetch or simply share some data to its children.